# What exactly is Z-Transform useful for?

Tags: transfer-function

What exactly is Z-Transform useful for in Signal Processing ?

Comment: Read this http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/econtrolhtml/sampled/sampled1.html#Why

Answer (score 4):

From the Wikipedia article "[Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform)":

> [The Z-transform] can be considered as a discrete-time equivalent of
>   the Laplace transform.

Hopefully, you have some idea how important the [Laplace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) transform (and the related Fourier transform) are to *continuous* time signal processing.

If so, then you have your answer.  If not, then start there.